# Any free/cheap bandwith shaping or network impairment software with API?

Tags: api, networking, trafficshaping

I'm looking for a (preferably) free software to install on a dual NIC box to shape badwidth and/or introduce packet loss, latency, etc.

Now I know dummynet and similar software but I need an API to control it. Maybe a simple RESTful http or SOAP based one. Preferably something more manageable than command line.

It may not be a production quality since I plan to use it for a demo/prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using "tc" in linux